# Special characters stopped working in xeLaTeX

Tags: xetex

I am using the font `ScaGoudy` with xeLatex and before i could use the special characters.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{ScaGoudy}
\begin{document}

\begin{quote}

k\d sity\=adin\=amavayavavat\=a\d m ni\'scita\d m janma t\=avat \\
tann\=astyeva kvacana kalita\d m kartradhi\d s\d th\=anah\={\i}nam

\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

And the output which i get is the following image [image]

Before this was working fine with the same font. Attached is the output
that it was working well

[image]

Any idea how i can make this work??

Comment: Any information about the font? Where can it be found, if it is free?

Comment: @egreg Hey sure. Here is the link: http://www.gauranga.org/files/sca_goudy.zip

Comment: Do you *really* think people will download a ZIP file this way? Surely not I. Provide a *link where to start the download*, so people can see what's about.

Comment: Hey there! Kindly dont get angry. Here is the link: http://www.gauranga.org/introduc.htm

Comment: As far as I can see, the font has no glyph such as `ś` or `ā` or `ḍ`, nor the combining accents.

Comment: But I am able to inser the symbols ś or ā or ḍ when i use Libre office. But I have to do that manually. Go to the option of selecting special characters and do it, which is quite painful.

Comment: Libreoffice is able to fake missing glyphs by getting them from other fonts, this won't work with xelatex. But didn't you claim it worked with xelatex?

Comment: LibreOffice is doing substitutions, as it is evident from the bottom picture: can you see that `ī` is from a different font?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes exactly. This definitely worked sometime before. Not sure why this ain't working now

Comment: I even tried someother font called "Sorts Mill Goudy" which does support some special characters. But then again `ś` and ḍ where not being supported. Only ā this works with that font.

Comment: Well it can't have been working with this font. Beside that quite a lot of glyphs are missing they are also in wrong positions. E.g. instead of ö I see a t with dot below. Imho this font is broken.

Comment: DejaVu Serif and Linux Libertine seems to have all those glyphs.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Emm. Thanks for your valuable inputs then :)